# filter an array of objects. what would i do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have an array with objects inside, like this:

```
const CurrentSchedule = [
   { name: "jão", 
     date:"22/10/2022",
     hour:"12:00"
   },
   { name: "jão", 
     date:"22/10/2022",
     hour:"08:00"
   }
]
```

and i have another array with hours to be used, like this

```
const hours =["08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00"]
```

and i want to create an another array with the hours but remove the hours that already are in the array CurrentSchedule. i tried to do a filter, like this

```
const updatedHours = hours.filter((hour)=> hour !== CurrentSchedule.hour)
```

but dont work. so, i tried to take only the value of hour from the CurrentSchedule with a map, then make a filter with this new array, but also dont work

```
const hoursToRemove = [];
CurrentSchedule.map((each)=> hoursToRemove.push(each.hour));
const updatedHours = hours.filter(hour => hour !== hoursToRemove)
```

dont work either. So i tried to do a for

```
let updatedHours = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i < CurrentSchedule.lenght ; i++){
   updatedHours = hours.filter(hour => hour !== CurrentSchedule[i].hour)
}
return updatedHours
```

but nothing that i tried worked. someone can help me to solve this problem? I'm a beginner dev.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to provide an example array you want the data to look like?

Answer (score 2):

You could get the used hours first and then filter `hours`.

```js
const
    currentSchedule = [{ name: "jão", date: "22/10/2022", hour: "12:00" }, { name: "jão", date: "22/10/2022", hour: "08:00" }],
    hours = ["08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00"],
    used = currentSchedule.map(({ hour }) => hour),
    result = hours.filter(h => !used.includes(h));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ty so much, now i can see were am i wrong

Answer (score 1):

You were almost right in your first approach. You have to check each hour of CurrentSchedules though, so one way of approaching this problem is mapping the main object in an array of hours:

```js
const CurrentSchedule = [
   { name: "jão", 
     date:"22/10/2022",
     hour:"12:00"
   },
   { name: "jão", 
     date:"22/10/2022",
     hour:"08:00"
   }
];

const hours =["08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00"];

console.log(hours.filter(h => !CurrentSchedule.map(x => x.hour).includes(h)))
```

Comment: ohh i see! now i get it. ty so much for the explanation